# Tempo de execução de vídeo youtube

Tags: php, youtube

Andei buscando e não encontrei nada concreto, sei que existe a API do youtube mas não encontrei nenhuma fonte certa.

Como posso verificar em `php` se o usuário assistiu ou não um vídeo do youtube incorporado ao meu site? Ou até mesmo contar quantos minutos o usuário assistiu?

Comment: Você chegou a ler na API se isso é possivel por ela? Se não for por ela, dificilmente será possivel externamente.

Comment: Dê uma lida nestas questões do SOen, elas aparentemente respondem a suas duas perguntas. [Is it possible to determine if a user finished to see an embedded youtube video with the api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014582/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-a-user-finished-to-see-an-embedded-youtube-video) e [Identify if user has watched a video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066454/identify-if-user-has-watched-a-video)

Comment: Nunca será possível determinar se ele assistiu o vídeo. Ele pode deixar o vídeo correr e ir na padaria buscar um pão e ao chegar fecha seu site. Não tome nenhuma decisão baseada no player ser assistido, pois a pessoa pode não estar na frente da tela.

Comment: @durtto não necessariamente se ele "assistiu o vídeo", mas se ele deu o play e executou o vídeo até o fim (mesmo que ele tenha ido na padaria durante essa execução)

Comment: Você quer saber se um humano assistiu todo o vídeo do seu site mesmo não estando na frente do pc?

Comment: Quando se trata de YouTube API eu costumo usar o JavaScript. Na API tem uma função chamada `onytplayerStateChange`. O `return` dessa funçã o sempre traz o **status** atual do vídeo. Se ele está pausado, se está em execução ou se ele foi terminado de ser visto, que no caso seria o status `0`. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#SubscribingEvents

Comment: Esse LINK https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo mostra pra você do lado direito os parâmetros do vídeo. Note que quando ele terminar, você pode pular para o final para ver, ele altera o `Player state` para `ended`, e se você ver o relatório embaixo, mostra que ele é nulo, ou `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando a API do google, que mostra o tempo se o usuário der play, pause ou se o vídeo terminar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
        events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case 0:
            alert('vídeo acabou');
            break;
        case 1:
            alert('começou em '+player.getCurrentTime());
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('pausado em '+player.getCurrentTime());
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

E é só passar a url dentro de um iframe:

```
<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: @DiegoFelipe foi através do seu link que consegui achar a solução, obrigada.